# JS setTimeout() repeats, isn't loop better than recursion syntax to prevent stack exhaustion?

Tags: javascript, loops, events, recursion, settimeout

The standard way to implement repeated execution of a callback (almost) exactly one second after the previous callback ended would be the (so-called) "recursive" syntax:

```
function callback_recurse(){
   // do something, if <condtion> break
   setTimeout(callback_recurse, 1000); 
}
setTimeout(callback_recurse, 1000); // first call
```

Why not use loop syntax instead?:

```
function callback(){
   // do something 
}
function loopcallbacks(){
    while (<condition>)
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
```

After all, you'll never run out of stack space using iterative loop syntax like you will using recursive syntax.

(Disclaimer: I'm answering my own question)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the second example would even be considered an option given that it's an endless loop.

Comment: First snippet is not recursive. It's pseudo recursive and i wouldn't expect it to grow the call stack. Also in the second snippet you are synchronously pushing countless callbacks to be executed 1000ms after they are inserted to the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

Using **setTimeout()** in the loop inside **loopcallbacks()** will not behave as expected, if you expect that there will be a one second interval between each task. Assume a loop of 5 iteration instead of the infinite one in your program. 
 Then the whole loop is executed in under a millisecond, and each of the 5 tasks is scheduled to be placed on the synchronous JS event queue one second later. They will run consecutively in order, but not each separated by a second. If it is an infinite loop as in your program will block and the stack will overflow before any task is executed.

You needn't worry about running out of stack space using the so-called "recursive" syntax in **callback_recurse()**.  Actually it is not true recursive because the calling function returns before the newly scheduled task runs, so the stack does not increase in size. Therefore you would never run out of stack space using the so-called "recursive" syntax.

The following program demonstrates both loop and recursive syntax:

First, the loop syntax is run.  The output format is

```
([index], time from start, time from previous task).
```

As you can see, all 5 tasks are run about 1 second after running the loop.  (Note, however, they are run consecutively and in correct  order - they are not running asynchronously).

Secondly, the so-called recursive syntax is run.  The output format is the same, and this time the results match the desired behavior.

```js
function time_ms() {
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.getTime();
  return t;
}
function makestr(d0,dlast,d,idx){
  var s0,s1;
  if (idx === 0) s0 = "*"; else s0 = (d-dlast).toString();
  s1 = (d-d0).toString()
 var s = "([" + idx.toString() + "]," + s0 + "," + s1 + "), ";
  return s;
}

function run1_sub(i,is_last){
    setTimeout(function() {
      d = time_ms();
      s = makestr(d0,dlast,d,i);
      dlast = d;
      document.getElementById("1").innerHTML += s;
      // maybe mixing metaphors, but this ensures that run2 starts after run1 finishes
      if (is_last)
        setTimeout(run2(),0) 
    }, 1000);
}

function run1() {
  var s = "";
  var i;
  var d0 = time_ms();
  var dlast = d0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
   run1_sub(i,i==4);
  }
}
var j = 0;
var d0 = time_ms();
var dlast = d0;

function run2() {
  var s = "";
  d = time_ms();
  s = makestr(d0,dlast,d,j);
  dlast = d;
  document.getElementById("2").innerHTML += s;
  j += 1;
  if (j < 5) 
    setTimeout(run2, 1000);
}

run1();  // run2() is first called from insde the last callback of run1()
```

```html
<div id="1">
</div>
<div id="2">
</div>
```

Comment: No callbacks will never run. *while(true)* is blocking

Comment: @Jonasw , for an infinite loop setTimeouts() that is true.